# 2nd GPU not showing in nvidia-smi in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, cuda

I've been having issues with my machine not detecting my second GPU (both RTX 3090s). This is not a new machine and is an issue that popped up a few weeks ago, which I resolved by rolling back to an older kernel (unknown version). But after a recent update, I lost that kernel and am stuck with this issue.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Swapping GPUs in their PCI slots to rule out a hardware issue
- Update to latest mobo BIOS
- Fresh 22.04 install for each driver install below
- Every NVIDIA CUDA install (>= 11.7) from the NVIDIA downloads page (deb local, deb network and run file)
- Every Ubuntu nvidia-driver* as far back as I can go to maintain a minimum CUDA version of 11.7
- Rolling back to an abritrarily old kernel version (5.15) using mainline
- Rolling forward to kernel 6.4
- Booting with a HDMI monitor attached to GPU 2

*Note that all older Ubuntu nvidia-drivers-5XX are transitional packages to either 525 or 535 (`apt search nvidia-driver`). The last driver I had both GPUs working was 515.

The single GPU that is listed (also my display GPU) does run CUDA workloads, but seems to make my system unstable/laggy when the job (PyTorch) starts for a few mins.

```
❯ uname -r
5.19.0-46-generic
```

```
❯ lspci | grep VGA
09:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090] (rev a1)
43:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090] (rev a1)
```

```
❯ nvidia-smi
Sat Jul  1 12:11:41 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.125.06   Driver Version: 525.125.06   CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:43:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   41C    P8    24W / 350W |    562MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1879      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                140MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2338    C+G   ...ome-remote-desktop-daemon      258MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2375      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               87MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3338      G   ...566776601308618822,262144       73MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`dmesg`
[Link to GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Anjum48/a691f4aab23386b04d443621a229a09e)

The weird thing is very occasionally, after a fresh CUDA install (not isolated to a single driver version) and a restart, the 2nd GPU does show up in `nvidia-smi`. But after a reboot is disappears again. Uninstalling and reinstalling CUDA can replicate this but it appears to be random (and not what I want to do each time I reboot)

Any ideas how I can get my machine working properly again?

[Link to nvidia-bug-report](https://gist.github.com/Anjum48/3a040c6418673604dec9108de2c6a79c)

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS was just upgraded from kernel 5.15.0-76 to 6.1.0-1015 and with that change, Nvidia drivers stopped working for me at all. Maybe you'll succeed with the 5.15 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dkms autoinstall
```

might help by rebuilding the Nvidia kernel modules.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the only solution I have found is to use `mainline` to install kernel version 5.15. This restored my second GPU in `nvidia-smi`.

I have no idea why the current 22.04.2 LTS image uses 5.19 as it states [here](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/livepatch/reference/kernels) that 22.04 LTS should be 5.15. It is also bizarre that a routine update essentially created this issue - I'm sure the main reason people use the LTS versions is to avoid this kind of issue.

Edit: Based on the [release notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668?_ga=2.83554710.1097158645.1688633890-1577079180.1688030335)

> Ubuntu Desktop will automatically opt-into v5.17 kernel on the latest generations of certified devices (linux-oem-22.04)

> Ubuntu Server defaults to a non-rolling LTS kernel v5.15 (linux-generic)

So it looks like 5.15 may only be for Ubuntu Server, and Ubuntu Desktop uses a rolling kernel. Shame the current kernel seems to have broken something...

Answer (score 0):

@Anjum Sayed, could you detail about what you did to restore it. I'm using a dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop and experiencing the same issue, where I cannot see the GPU RTX 3090 core anymore:

```
Loading new nvidia-465.19.01 DKMS files…
Building for 5.15.0-76-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.15.0-76-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: ‘/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-465.0.crash’
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-76-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/465.19.01/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-465 (–configure):
installed nvidia-dkms-465 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers-465:
cuda-drivers-465 depends on nvidia-dkms-465 (>= 465.19.01); however:
Package nvidia-dkms-465 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers-465 (–configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers:
cuda-drivers depends on cuda-drivers-465 (= 465.19.01-1); however:
Package cuda-drivers-465 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers (–configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-465:
nvidia-driver-465 depends on nvidia-dkms-465 (= 465.19.01-0ubuntu1); however:
Package nvidia-dkms-465 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-465 (–configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-runtime-11-3:
cuda-runtime-11-3 depends on cuda-drivers (>= 465.19.01); however:
Package cuda-drivers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-runtime-11-3 (–configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-demo-suite-11-3:
cuda-demo-suite-11-3 depends on cuda-runtimeNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
-11-3; however:
Package cuda-runtime-11-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-demo-suite-11-3 (–configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-11-3:
cuda-11-3 depends on cuda-runtime-11-3 (>= 11.3.1); however:
Package cuda-runtime-11-3 is not configured yet.
cuda-11-3 depends on cuda-demo-suite-11-3 (>= 11.3.58); however:
Package cuda-demo-suite-11-3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-11-3 (–configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda:
cuda depends on cuda-11-3 (>= 11.3.1); however:
Package cuda-11-3 is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package cuda (–configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.7) …
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-76-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
nvidia-dkms-465
cuda-drivers-465
cuda-drivers
nvidia-driver-465
cuda-runtime-11-3
cuda-demo-suite-11-3
cuda-11-3
cuda
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Any update on this? I am having the same issue.